# Replace second group of a regex match on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of about 1000 rows and my requirement is to replace all characters that appear after username: to a common string (say 'users').

I'm making use of the following regex that suits my problem and I can match all usernames in the second group which I want to replace with 'users'

Regex:

```
"(?i)(\busername\b\s?|\buname\s?)+[;|:]
(\s?[a-z-A-Z0-9@:!+=#$%^&*-]{5,})"
```

Test data:

```
 username : user111
    uname : user212
```

Expected Output:

```
username : users
uname : users
```

Also I wanted to do this operation on a large dataset so i'm looking if there are any efficient ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could use regex for this, but sometimes the simplest thing to to is split and join such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':['username : user111','uname : user212']})

df['values'].apply(lambda x: ': '.join([x.split(':')[0], 'users']))
```

Or if you'd like to avoid lambda:

```
df['values'].str.split(':').str.get(0) + ': users'
```

Output

```
             values
0  username : users
1     uname : users
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wanted to replace specific occurrence of a pattern to a common string since I'm working on a machine learning task and that's why I picked up regex. So I would like to do the same operation on a password. Strings that appear after the word password: would be replaced to another common string similar to username. So any other ways of achieving this?

Comment: You can build a dictionary and use that to replace {regex1:'replace_value1',regex2:replace_value2'}